# Save Button in Button to XML

Tags: xml, winforms, file, button, save

I have winforms application.
There is "programmatically" done button and is Added to Controls of winform, in this button is "programmatically" done next button, and this button is Added to Control of first button, then there is third Button, which is inside of second Button a is Added to Control of second button.There is some information written to last button like some labels. I need to save it to XML to be loaded later THX [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9GMT.png):)

Tried export controls to XML - not lucky

Comment: When you say "manually", do you mean added "programmatically" by your code at run-time, or that you did it interactively in the Form Designer as usual?

Comment: Yes,, like you wrote, programmatically, by my code at run-time. User can choose the size.

Comment: User can fulfill some device with data busses and to this data busses can be placed some units. Can add, remove and change the sizes...so I had idea, that it could be nice to do it with buttons. And with time a found, that every button has its own Control, so it passed to my plan how to do it :)